# Restoring Non-Renewable Subscriptions

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit, non-renewing-subscription

I am working with Non-Renewable Subscriptions and In-App purchases for the first time and I am having issues publishing my app because of the restoration of old purchases.

Based on this code that I have:

1) Should I call my restoreProduct method on the paymentQueue or on the paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished ?

2) Neither the "case .restored" or the paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished are being triggered, what am I doing wrong and how could I fix it?

Edited:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class SubscriptionViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var moreDetails: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    // For the in app purchase
    let productIdentifiers = Set([Constants.oneMonthSubscription, Constants.threeMonthsSubscription,
        Constants.sixMonthsSubscription, Constants.yearSubscription])

    var basePrice = Double()
    var product: SKProduct?
    var productsArray = Array<SKProduct>()
    var errorCount = 0 
    var user = User()
    var newUser = true
    var cameFromLogin = false
    var processing = false
    var userOneSignalId = NSString()
    var service = ""
    var transactionDate = 0.0
    var transactionId = ""
    var count = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        requestProductData()        
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
    }


    // Pop-up to indicate an error in the credentials or the authentication process
    func showSignUpError(_ message: NSString){

        let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message as String, preferredStyle: .alert)

        let dismissAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: { (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) in optionMenu.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) })

        optionMenu.addAction(dismissAction)

        self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension SubscriptionViewController:  UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.productsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let product = self.productsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section]
        let productIdentifier = product.productIdentifier
        let price = product.price
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PromoCell", for: indexPath) as! PromoCell

        cell.subscription.tag = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section
        cell.subscription.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SubscriptionViewController.didTapButton(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)

           cell.subscription.setTitle( "$\(price)",for: UIControlState())

        return cell

    }

    func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton!){

        if !processing{ // Will proccess just one purchase request at the same time

            // Section to hide/show
            let tappedSection = sender.tag;
            self.processing = true
            print("User selected : \(self.productsArray[tappedSection].productIdentifier)")
            self.buyProduct(self.productsArray[tappedSection])
        }
    }
}

extension SubscriptionViewController :  SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver{

    // Sends a request to find out which products are available for purchase
    func requestProductData(){

        self.tableView.isHidden = true

        // Checks if In-App purchase is enabled
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {

            // Requests the product list/set
            let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: self.productIdentifiers)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()

        } else { // Shows an error message and options to enable the In-App Purchases for the app

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "In-App Purchases Not Enabled", message: "Please enable In App Purchase in Settings", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { alertAction in

                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                // Opens the settings so the user can enable the In-App purchase
                let url: URL? = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
                if url != nil{
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
                }

            }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { alertAction in
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    // Recieves the answer for the previous request
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

        self.productsArray = response.products
        productsArray.sort(by: {$0.price.int32Value < $1.price.int32Value})

        for item in self.productsArray {
            if item.productIdentifier.range(of: "1month") != nil {
                self.basePrice = item.price.doubleValue //Price for the most basic subscription
                break
            }
        }

        let productsNotFound = response.invalidProductIdentifiers

        for product in productsNotFound{
            print("Product not found: \(product)")
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            Loading.stopRotation()
        }

        self.tableView.isHidden = false
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // Asks for confirmation when buying a product
    func buyProduct(_ product: SKProduct) {

        Loading.startRotation()
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    }


    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

        for transaction in transactions  {

            Loading.stopRotation()

            switch transaction.transactionState {

            case .purchased:

                print("Transaction Approved")
                print("Product Identifier: \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")

                print("Purchasing... Transaction ID: " + transaction.transactionIdentifier!)
                print("Purchasing... Transaction Date: " + String(describing: transaction.transactionDate?.timeIntervalSince1970))

                print("\n\n--------------\n\n")

                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

                transactionDate = (transaction.transactionDate?.timeIntervalSince1970)!
                transactionId = transaction.transactionIdentifier!

                self.deliverProduct(transaction)

            case .restored:

                let transaction = SKPaymentTransaction()
                transaction.setValue(NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1480468782), forKey: "transactionDate")
                transaction.setValue( "1000000254866709", forKey: "transactionIdentifier")

                print("Product Identifier: \(transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier)")
                print("Restoring... Transaction ID: " + (transaction.original?.transactionIdentifier)!)
                print("Restoring... Transaction Date: " + String(describing: transaction.original?.transactionDate?.timeIntervalSince1970))
                print("\n\n--------------\n\n")

                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

               transactionDate = (transaction.original?.transactionDate?.timeIntervalSince1970)!
               transactionId = (transaction.original?.transactionIdentifier)!

                self.restoreProduct(transaction)

            case .failed:

                print("Transaction Failed")
                print(transaction.error)

                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                if transaction.error?._code == 0 || transaction.error?._code == 2 {
                    self.errorCount += 1 //

                    if self.errorCount > 3 { // We give the app three chances to connect
                        print("Error connecting to the iTunes Store")
                        self.showSignUpError(Constants.iTunnesConnectionError as NSString)
                    }

                }else{

                    self.showSignUpError(Constants.signUpError as NSString)
                }


                self.processing = false
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }


    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {

        print("Transactions Restored .")

        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            let transaction: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
            print(transaction.transactionIdentifier ?? "Missing Transaction ID")
        }
    }


    func deliverProduct(_ transaction:SKPaymentTransaction) {



    }

    func restoreProduct(_ transaction:SKPaymentTransaction) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You should restore purchases in the `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions` function. The `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` justblets you know the restoration process is complete in case you want to update your UI.  However, restoring non-renewing subscriptions is up to you; the App Store does not provide restoration for non-renewing subscriptions. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW2

Comment: Thank you for the answer to the first question. Regarding question number 2 I know that  the App Store does not provide restoration for non-renewing subscriptions. But when testing the IAP is says something like: "you already bought this product, would you like to restore?" and then the .restored case is never triggered so I can not start my restoration process. That is my main concern

Comment: You need to provide more code; Are you calling `finishTransaction` on the paymentQueue?  Are you calling `restoreCompletedTransactions` on the paymentQueue?

Comment: I added all the code of this VC. I do call finishTransaction but I am do not know how should I call restoreCompletedTransactions

Comment: You would normally call `restoreCompletedTransactions` in response to the user clicking on a "Restore" button

Comment: Thank you, I think I am on the right track now

Comment: @ur3k i am facing the same problem. How did you overcome it?